# How to get own URL or hostname in a ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, url, service-worker

In the ServiceWorker JavaScript code itself (not the page code), I would like to know my own URL. Or at least the own host.

I need this, because I want different cache behavior for resources from my own server and resources from other servers.

In other words: `event.request.url` is allways a URL with host and path (like `https://example.com/index.html`). I need to know, if this URL is from the same host as the ServiceWorker itself is from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside of a service worker execution context, `self` is set to the [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope), which inherits from [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope). There's a [`location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/location) on `WorkerGlobalScope` that can give you the info you want.

You can put that into practice to solve your problem via a helper method like:

```
function isSameOrigin(urlString) {
  const urlOrigin = (new URL(urlString)).origin;
  return urlOrigin === self.location.origin;
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference between comparing same hostname vs. same host (hostname+port) vs. same origin (scheme+host) in practise - when defining cache logic in sw? Is it safe to use host rather than origin to ignore the difference between http vs. https?